# I want to filter data (rows) on the basis of datetime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I want to filter my data (rows) on the basis on a datetime column. For example I want the data (row) when the datetime column is last date of month (31/30) at 00:00:00.000 time.

I have the data file which have a column with data like 2018-10-28 00:56:98.003 and want the the data of last date of the month at 00:00:00.000.
[the image show the sample database which i have and i have to filter the data according to TimeCol(column name) that is on the last date of month(31,30,28)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w42Es.png)
and then after filtering the data i want to perform some arithmetic operations on it

Comment: Please make this a complete question by adding sample input and output data.  And also add your current query.

Comment: Find out the month from your date column, then use where clause with the last date of selected month or whatever is your condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think **EOMONTH** function is something you are looking for:

```sql
         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp

         CREATE TABLE #temp (dtDatetime DATETIME NOT NULL)

         INSERT #temp
         SELECT '20190112 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190131 01:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190131 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190214 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190228 01:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190317 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190331 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
         SELECT '20190331 01:00:00.000' 


         SELECT * FROM #temp
         WHERE dtDatetime = EOMONTH(dtDatetime)

returns:

 - 2019-01-31 00:00:00.000 
 - 2019-02-28 00:00:00.000
 - 2019-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: i want to filter the data on the basis of datetime

Comment: so if you have a few records in table and you filer data in that table by reference to datatime column in WHERE clouse just like abowe you can get all matching records, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, the step takes you to know the current end of month of the current row. Then filter using LINQ -> Where(..) extension method.
Here's the example:

```
public class Row
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

List<Row> rows = new List<Row>
{
    new Row
    {
        Data = "Data 1",
        DateTime = new DateTime(2019,1,21,21,10,0)
    },

    new Row
    {
        Data = "Data 2",
        DateTime = new DateTime(2019,1,1,23,0,0)
    },

    new Row
    {
        Data = "Data 3",
        DateTime = new DateTime(2019,2,28,0,0,0)
    },

    new Row
    {
        Data = "Data 4",
        DateTime = new DateTime(2019,3,14,13,15,12)
    },

    new Row
    {
        Data = "Data 5",
        DateTime = new DateTime(2019,07,31,21,10,0)
    },

    new Row
    {
        Data = "Data 6",
        DateTime = new DateTime(2019,06,30,0,0,0)
    }
};

List<Row> filteredRows = rows.Where(row =>
{
    //This functions used to get the last day in a month
    int endOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(row.DateTime.Year, row.DateTime.Month);
    return (
          row.DateTime.Day == endOfMonth &&
          row.DateTime.Hour == 0 &&
          row.DateTime.Minute == 0 &&
          row.DateTime.Second == 0 &&
          row.DateTime.Millisecond == 0
    );
}).ToList();
```

The filteredRws Variable will contain data -> "Data 3" and "Data 6".

Regards,

Mirza